# exclude some source files from being deployed to the container

Tags: eclipse, deployment, ear-file

I have a EJB project in Eclipse that contains two source folder "ejbModule" and "test"

where `ejbModule` contains source code for ejbs and `test` contains source code for the JUnit tests.

when I export the ear file using the right click -> export, I found the the .class files of the Junit tests are being exported within the EAR.

EDIT:

So, how I can prevent these source files from being deployed to the container, but in the same time I still need eclipse to consider them as source files??

(I am **not** asking the same question here: [exclude files from jar or war in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489179/exclude-files-from-jar-or-war-in-eclipse) )

Answer (score 2):

In eclipse 3.6 right click on the project, press properties. Then go to "deployment assembly" property page. There you can define, what are the parts of the project artifact.

Update:
On the other hand, the GUI of WTP do not support everything the builder can handle. Source folders can be easily excluded, if you edit the .`settings/org.eclipse.wst.common.component` file (both in 3.5 and 3.6 eclipse) in project root. It does look like this (example from one of my projects):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project-modules id="moduleCoreId" project-version="1.5.0">
    <wb-module deploy-name="gui">
        <wb-resource deploy-path="/WEB-INF/classes" source-path="/src/main/java"/>
        <wb-resource deploy-path="/WEB-INF/classes" source-path="/src/main/resources"/>
        <wb-resource deploy-path="/" source-path="/src/main/webapp"/>
        <dependent-module deploy-path="/WEB-INF/lib" handle="module:/resource/aoprules/aoprules">
            <dependency-type>uses</dependency-type>
        </dependent-module>
        <dependent-module deploy-path="/WEB-INF/lib" handle="module:/resource/base/base">
            <dependency-type>uses</dependency-type>
        </dependent-module>
        <property name="context-root" value="gui"/>
        <property name="java-output-path" value="/gui/target/classes"/>
    </wb-module>
</project-modules>
```

You simply remove the `project-modules/wb-module/wb-resource` element, which has the `src/test`as `source-path` attribute. Then refresh project.

Comment: In 3.5 i guess it is called "Java EE dependencies".