# Exclude /WebContent/images folder from war in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, directory, war

How can I configure eclipse in a way that the /images folder under /WebContent is not included in the war exported file ? I see how to exclude files and folders but under the /src container.

Comment: See [this question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489179/exclude-files-from-jar-or-war-in-eclipse)

Comment: It works for items under /src, I need to exclude objects under /WebContent

Comment: The comment on the answer suggests it will work for WebContent too.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure exactly why you'd want to do that, but here are two options:

- Move your image folder OUT of WebContent (if you don't need them in the war, why are they here in the first place?)
- In the project properties (Deployment Assembly tab, although that might vary with your version of Eclipse), remove the line telling eclipse to include WebContent in the war and individually add all other folders/files