# Exclude files in jar from going into the apk

Tags: android, eclipse, ant, adt

I recently added some new jar's to my **android** project. Some of the jars contain version.properties. One of them even contains a README.TXT.

How can I tell eclipse/adt/ant to exclude files from getting into the apk?

Obviously I can unzip the apk, remove the files, zip, sign & zipline... but I was hoping to solve it at source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are creating the jar files from your own project, you right click the project -> Select Export -> Under Java select JAR file -> Then you can choose which files to include when the jar gets created. So deselect whichever resources you don't want included in the Jar file.

If this isn't what you are looking for, you could also try adding those files to the exclusion folder in the build configuration. Here's a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489179/exclude-files-from-jar-or-war-in-eclipse) that might help.

Comment: these are downloaded jars. But I guess nobody will hold me from decompiling them, remove files and compile them again

Comment: @taoufik: You do not need to decompile them. Just open them in any ZIP file manager and delete the file(s) in question.

Comment: Removed files out of the zip files using 'zip -d file.jar unwanted.txt'. Thanks both Dyarish & CommonsWare!